# regex in php to get two strings between slashes

Tags: php, regex

I have string, which have following syntax:

```
$string="/foo/XXX/bar/YYY"
```

and I need to get XXX and YYY. It is quite simple regex, but I'm a bit struggling with syntax in php, so could you help me out? :)

Comment: Does it always follow that syntax? Could you explode it and get the 1,3 index? `explode('/', $string)[2 & 4]`

Comment: _It is quite simple regex_. Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use explode():

```
$string= trim("/foo/XXX/bar/YYY", "/");
$parts = explode("/", $string);

$xxx = $parts[1];
```

Comment: +1, completely right! :D Unless the question is different (like only caps SSS, or DDD)

Comment: thank you, I always forget on this kind of functions :-)

Answer (score 1):

No need of regex:

1. Use explode to get an array
2. Get array element 2 and 4

**Code:**

```
$arr = explode('/', "/foo/XXX/bar/YYY");
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => foo
    [2] => XXX
    [3] => bar
    [4] => YYY
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    preg_split('/\//', $string);
```

would give you an array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "XXX"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "YYY"
}
```

So you can access $array[1] and $array[3].

Or use a foreach-loop and the %-Operator do get the values of every even key...